# Link Raspberry Pi #1 to Rapsberry Pi #2 using AWS as MQTT Broker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, mqtt, aws-iot

So I have a Raspberry Pi #1 that will publish a MQTT Message to AWS through a topic `sensors/Button`. This will trigger when a button is pressed, as shown below.

```
# Import SDK packages
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

button = Button(13, pull_up=False)

def callMQTT():
    print("button is pressed.Sending to MQTT")
    mqtt_message = "{\"message\":\"button_pressed\"}"
    print(mqtt_message)
    my_rpi.publish("sensors/Button", mqtt_message, 1)
    print("Message Published!")
    sleep(5)


host="host.amazonaws.com"
rootCAPath = "rootca.pem"
certificatePath = "certificate.pem.crt"
privateKeyPath = "private.pem.key"

try:
    my_rpi = AWSIoTMQTTClient("basicPubSub")
    my_rpi.configureEndpoint(host,8883)
    my_rpi.configureCredentials(rootCAPath, privateKeyPath, certificatePath)

    my_rpi.configureOfflinePublishQueueing(-1)  # Infinite offline Publish queueing
    my_rpi.configureDrainingFrequency(2)  # Draining: 2 Hz

    # Connect and subscribe to AWS IoT
    my_rpi.connect()
    print("Connection Succesful")
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])

button.when_pressed = callMQTT
pause()
```

On Raspberry Pi #2, it will try to subscribe the MQTT from AWS using the same host, same Thing, same key and same certificate as Raspbery Pi #1. If a message is received, it will sound the buzzer and light up the LED as shown below.

```
# Import SDK packages
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import Buzzer,LED
import random
import sys
from datetime import datetime

bz = Buzzer(22)
led = LED(18)

# Custom MQTT message callback
def customCallback(client, userdata, message):
    print("Received a new message: ")
    print(message.payload)
    print("from topic: ")
    print(message.topic)
    print("--------------\n\n")
        timestring = str(datetime.now())
    print("Doorbell pressed")
    bz.on()
    led.blink()
    sleep(1)
    bz.off()
    led.off()

host="host.amazonaws.com"
rootCAPath = "rootca.pem"
certificatePath = "certificate.pem.crt"
privateKeyPath = "private.pem.key"

try:
    my_rpi = AWSIoTMQTTClient("basicPubSub")
    my_rpi.configureEndpoint(host, 8883)
    my_rpi.configureCredentials(rootCAPath, privateKeyPath, certificatePath)

    my_rpi.configureOfflinePublishQueueing(-1)  # Infinite offline Publish queueing
    my_rpi.configureDrainingFrequency(2)  # Draining: 2 Hz
    my_rpi.configureConnectDisconnectTimeout(10)  # 10 sec
    my_rpi.configureMQTTOperationTimeout(5)  # 5 sec

    # Connect and subscribe to AWS IoT
    my_rpi.connect()
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])

while True:
my_rpi.subscribe("sensors/Button", 1, customCallback)
sleep(2)
```

However, this is not possible. When both programs run at the same time, Rasberry Pi #2 will always timeout. For some reason it allows 1 connection at a time only.
I try to subscribe the topic directly through AWS when I run Raspberry Pi #1 code. It displays the message on AWS. Also, if I try to publish a message directly on AWS and run Raspberry Pi #2 code only, it works as well, but not when both running the code. The error I got on Raspberry Pi #2 is this:

> No handlers could be found for logger
>   "AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.protocol.mqttCore" Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "Doorbell_Indoor.py", line 72, in 
>       my_rpi.subscribe("sensors/Button", 1, customCallback)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/MQTTLib.py",
>   line 491, in subscribe
>       return self._mqttCore.subscribe(topic, QoS, callback)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/mqttCore.py",
>   line 416, in subscribe
>       raise subscribeTimeoutException() AWSIoTPythonSDK.exception.AWSIoTExceptions.subscribeTimeoutException

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Each client must have a unique client ID, best guess is that the string passed to `AWSIoTMQTTClient()` is the client ID, make these different and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it documented in the Python SDK docs, but in the Java SDK docs it says:

> clientId - the client ID uniquely identify a MQTT connection. Two
>   clients with the same client ID are not allowed to be connected
>   concurrently to a same endpoint.

Try using a unique `clientId` value for each connection instead of `"basicPubSub"`.

Comment: where can I find the clientId? AWS doesn't seem to have it. Do I make up my own clientId?

Comment: You make it up. You should use a different id for each running script.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html

> The message broker uses the client ID to identify each client. The client ID is passed in from the client to the message broker as part of the MQTT payload. Two clients with the same client ID are not allowed to be connected concurrently to the message broker. When a client connects to the message broker using a client ID that another client is using, a CONNACK message will be sent to both clients >and the currently connected client will be disconnected.

You either have to pass in a unique string per a client to AWSIoTMQTTClient() or an empty string.  If you pass an empty string for the client id the AWS IoT Gateway will assign a random client id for you on connection.

Change the AWSIoTMQTTClient call from

```
my_rpi = AWSIoTMQTTClient("basicPubSub")
```

to

```
my_rpi = AWSIoTMQTTClient("")
```

and each of the RPIs will be assigned a unique random client id on connection.  AWS don't recommend doing this at scale but it is fine for tests.  You also lose the ability to use the clientid in policies.